# How to Fit Prediction values in Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have the prediction results as follows:

```
Predictions= [[0.39963388 0.44170195 0.37929803 0.1575233  0.24030758]]
```

And my labels are as follows:

```
Columns: ['desert', 'mountains', 'sea', 'sunset', 'trees']
```

how to make this two values i.e. `Predictions` and `Columns` into one dataframe?

as:

```
      Labels  Columns
0     desert  0.39963388
1  mountains  0.44170195
2        sea  0.37929803
3     sunset  0.1575233
4      trees  0.24030758
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(Columns,Predictions[0])),orient='index')` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
Predictions= [[0.39963388, 0.44170195, 0.37929803, 0.1575233, 0.24030758]]
df = pd.DataFrame(Predictions, columns= ['desert', 'mountains', 'sea', 'sunset', 'trees']).T.reset_index()
df.columns = ['Labels', 'Predictions']
print(df)
```

```
      Labels  Predictions
0     desert     0.399634
1  mountains     0.441702
2        sea     0.379298
3     sunset     0.157523
4      trees     0.240308
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Predictions= [[0.39963388, 0.44170195, 0.37929803, 0.1575233,  0.24030758]]
Columns= ['desert', 'mountains', 'sea', 'sunset', 'trees']


dict_val={"Columns":Columns,"Predictions":Predictions[0]}
print(dict_val)
df=pd.DataFrame(dict_val,columns=["Columns","Predictions"])
df.rename({"Columns":"Labels",
    "Predictions":"Columns"
})
```